# Can't get value (double) from another Listener

Tags: android, android-intent

I have problem. I have two activities: **MainActivity** and **Pop** and I want to send number(double) from Main to Pop, I have number here(IntCountValue)

```
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String countValue = txtCount.getText().toString();
            double IntCountValue = Double.parseDouble(countValue);
            IntCountValue +=1.5;
            txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(IntCountValue));
        }
    });
```

and I want to use it here

```
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Pop.class);
            intent.putExtra("Coins", IntCountValue);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

But it can't resolve symbol. Can someone help me please?

**EDIT:**

Thx guys for help, i fixed it, but i have another problem..

styles.xml

```
    <style name="AppTheme.CustomTheme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

SecondActivity(PopUp):

```
public class PopUp extends Activity {
TextView txtCount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popwindow);

    txtCount = findViewById(R.id.textView12);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int) (width*.8), (int) (height*.6));

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras == null) {

    }
    else
    {
        String bananas = extras.getString("Bananas");
        txtCount.setText(bananas);
    }


}
```

}

When i click out of this box, this box appears again but instead of the value(bananas)is displayed word TextView, can i fix it somehow..?

Comment: Didn't you know about passing values using Intent between activities ?

Comment: lol. an upvote.

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: check the putExtra methods :  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html